# how to change ProFTPd port without using "passive mode"

Tags: ftp, default, port

I just re-installed Ubuntu server 10.04 and decided to change all of my default ports to get a little extra security. Everything works fine, except when I decided to change the FTP (ProFTPd) port from the standard 21 to 3521. No problems with firewalls or port forwarding. ProFTPd was restarted but when I am trying to connect to it,even though it does respond, it throws the client (FileZilla) into a "passive mode" and then never goes into listing a directory.
 I don't really want to use the "passive mode" and I have it disabled in proftpd.conf, but nevertheless I can't seem to change the default port otherwise and make it working. It does seem to work fine on port 21. FYI, the proftpd was installed as a standalone daemon, if that matters somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured this out after reading this page: [link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) . It appears that most FTP connections are indeed "passive" and the problem with "active" connections comes from the use of firewalls on the client side since FTP server is initiating an outgoing "data" connection to the client on some **random** port. In passive mode the client initiates both "command" and "data" connections to the server and hence the firewall isn't a problem, but you should specify which "passive" ports to use on the server. I enabled 3520 and 3521 PassivePorts and it's now working

Comment: I didn't, it just seems sort of counterintuitive to accept my own answers. :)

Comment: It might :) but the whole point is the next time someone says "I can't get my proftpd to work after changing the port", here's a similar question _with answer_ that is worth reading. :)

Answer (score 0):

[FTP Active Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview) by definition requires the server to initiate its outgoing connections from port `L-1`. Does your firewall allow outgoing connections from port `3520` as well?

From the [FTP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt):

> 3.2.  ESTABLISHING DATA CONNECTIONS
>
> ```
>   The mechanics of transferring data consists of setting up the data
>   connection to the appropriate ports and choosing the parameters
>   for transfer.  Both the user and the server-DTPs have a default
>   data port.  The user-process default data port is the same as the
>   control connection port (i.e., U).  The server-process default
>   data port is the port adjacent to the control connection port
>   (i.e., L-1).
> ```
>
> ...
>
> 3.3.  DATA CONNECTION MANAGEMENT
>
> ```
>   Default Data Connection Ports:  All FTP implementations must
>   support use of the default data connection ports, and only the
>   User-PI may initiate the use of non-default ports.
>
>   Negotiating Non-Default Data Ports:   The User-PI may specify a
>   non-default user side data port with the PORT command.  The
>   User-PI may request the server side to identify a non-default
>   server side data port with the PASV command.  Since a connection
>   is defined by the pair of addresses, either of these actions is
>   enough to get a different data connection, still it is permitted
>   to do both commands to use new ports on both ends of the data
>   connection.
> ```

You might wish to take the opportunity to change your users to [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol), a much nicer protocol.

Comment: 3520? No, the firewall is for "inbound" connections only, not "outgoing". I never had it enabled on port 20 either, but it works just find with only port 21 enabled. I just tried to enable it on 3520 too, just in case, but it's still not working.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured this out after reading this page: [link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html). It appears that most FTP connections are indeed "passive" and the problem with "active" connections comes from the use of firewalls of the client since FTP server is initiating an outgoing "data" connection to the client on some **random** port. In passive mode the client initiates both "command" and "data" connections to the server and hence the firewall isn't a problem, but you should specify which "passive" ports to use on the server. I enabled 3520 and 3521 PassivePorts and it's now working

Comment: @techexpert, excellent :) I suggest moving your comment to an answer, so you can accept it, and hopefully it'll be that much more visible to others in the future. Thanks for the report. :)